# The new prediction label is always changing with PCA after Kmean

Tags: python, k-means, pca

I am facing a problem that I am trying to do a Kmean clustering after PCA, when I want to cluster a new data, the prediction label is always changing (i.e. [2] to [3] to [1]....)

```
     #X is pre-defined dataset
        pca = PCA(n_components=2)
        reduced_data = pca.fit_transform(X)
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4)
        kmeans.fit_transform(reduced_data)

for filename in os.listdir(directoryName):
    if filename.endswith('.wav'): 
        (fs,rate)=wav.read(directoryName + "/" +filename)
        mfcc_feat = mfcc(rate,fs,nfft=1200)
        fbank_feat = logfbank(rate,fs,nfft=1200)
        features = mean_features(mfcc_feat)
        reduced_data = pca.transform([features])
        y = kmeans.predict(reduced_data)
        print (y)
```

And the output is:

```
[1]
[1]
[1]
```

But when I ran the code second time without modification:

```
[2]
[2]
[2]
```

And it keeps changing all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to have with your code is that **k-means** are initializing centroid randomly every time that's why your results are getting varied. To fix it, do have a look at below given piece of code:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n, random_state=42)
```

You can specify any value for the random_state parameter. It makes your result reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say without runnable example but you have to have in mind that K-means are not a deterministic algorithm but a stochastic one with random initialization, which means that you can get different clusters every time (or the **same clusters but with different labels**) - you start by randomly initializing the cluster centers and then iteratively move the centers to better locations - see the visualization and the description at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering.

Comment: Hi @Vladimir, I checked the prediction labels of dataset, it also keeps changing when I keep running the code. It matches the label with new input data since I extracted three from dataset. I am wondering is there a way to fix the labels for every time I run the code?